# Is there an Eclipse plugin which can perform comment translations from one language to another?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a codebase where most of the comments are in a language which I don't understand yet and I would like to avoid cluttering my browser with Google Translate tabs. Is there an Eclipse plugin which can perform translations?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about such a plug-in, but there is this extension point in JDT, which lets you add custom hover/tooltips. You may create such an extension which uses google translator to provide a (rough) translation as tooltip for the current comment block. The ext. point is called:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers
```

This way you don't have to manipulate the source files at all.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Translate Eclipse plugin](https://code.google.com/p/google-translate-eclipse-plugin/). Disclaimer: I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/source-code-translation-eclipse

I developed it because I am currently facing the same problem as you do